# docker and product versions

Tags: release, docker, product

I am working for a product company and we do make lot of releases of the product. In the current approach to test multiple releases, we create separate VM and install all infrastructure softwares(db, app server etc) on top of it. Later we deploy the application WARs on the respective VM. Recently, I came across docker and it seems to be much helpful. Hence I started exploring it with the examples listed on the site. But, I am not able to find a way as how docker can be applied to build environment suitable to various releases?

1. Each product version will have db schema changes.
2. Each application WARs will have enhancements/defects etc.

Consider below example.
Every month, our company is releasing a new version of software and hence in order to support/fix defects we create VMs per release. Given the fact that if the application's overall size is 2 gb and OS takes close to 5 gb (apart from space it will also take up system resources for extra overhead). The VMs are required to restore any release and test any support issues reported against it. But looking at the additional infrastructure requirements, it seems that its very costly affair.

Can docker have everything required to run an application inside a container/image?

Can docker pack an application which consists of multiple WARs/DB schemas and when started allocate appropriate port?

Will there be any space/memory/speed differences compared to VM and docker assuming above scenario?

Do you think docker is still appropriate solution or should we continue using VMs? Can someone share pointers on how I can achieve above requirements with docker?

Comment: the question is not about programming. http://serverfault.com/ is a much better place for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: Yes, docker can run most applications inside a container.

Docker runs a single process inside each container. When using VMs or real servers, this one process is usually the init system which starts all system services. With docker it is usually your app.

This difference will get you faster startup times for your app (not starting the whole operating system). The trade off is that, if you depend on system services (such as cron, sshd…) you will need to start them yourself. There are some base images that provide a more "VM-like" environment… check [phusion's baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) for instance. To start more than a single process, you can also use a process manager such as [supervisord](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/).

Going forward, the recommended (although not required) approach is to start one process in each container (one per application server, one per database server, and so on) and not use containers as VMs.

Docker has no problems allocating ports either. It even has an explicit command on the Dockerfile: [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#expose). Exposed ports can also be published on the docker host with the [`--publish` argument of `run`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run) so you don't even need to know the IP assigned to the container.

Regarding used space, you will probably see important savings. Docker images are created by stacking filesystem layers… this means that the common layers are only stored once on the server. In your setup, you will likely only have one copy of the base operating system layer (with VMs, you have a copy on each VM).

On memory you will probably see less significant savings (mostly caused by not starting all the operating system services). Speed is still a subject of research… A few things clear so far is that for faster IO you will need to use docker volumes and that for network heavy use cases you should use host networking. Check the IBM research "[An Updated Performance Comparison of Virtual Machines and Linux Containers](http://domino.research.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/papers/0929052195DD819C85257D2300681E7B/$File/rc25482.pdf)" for details. Or a summary like [InfoQ's](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/vm-containers-performance).

Comment: Hi Abel, Thanks for your post. I am not intending docker to automate the script execution. But what I am intending to look for is that how docker can be applied to a product development company. I will be adding an example to my original question.

Comment: Thanks @Abel, for your response. May be the way I am trying to compare docker with VMs is wrong and I need to explore further. Anyways I will select your response as answer as it has helped me to clear most of my thoughts.

Comment: I would not say "wrong". You can use docker as a traditional vm… that makes for a nice migration path. At some point in the future you might want to adopt Docker-isms on you setup.